# Building FFmpeg on RHEL4

Tags: ffmpeg, makefile, rhel

StackOverflow has yet to fail me, so don't let me down this time!

I need to build FFmpeg on RHEL4 ... yes, 4!

The version of `make` on RHEL4 is `3.80`, and the Makefile that `./configure` generates when configuring FFmpeg does not seem to be compatible. When I `make` it throws a parse error every time.

This happens on pretty much every software pkg I try and build.

My applications group (at work) will not upgrade this machine, so please skip the suggestions to upgrade to RHEL5 or 6.

What are my options for installing FFmpeg?

Comment: What's the error? Maybe we can figure out a way around the problem.

Comment: I build GNU Make 3.80 (comes from 2002) and tried building FFmpeg. I got: "unterminated call to function `foreach': missing `)'. Stop." Googling for this problem reveals other FFmpeg users who have had the same problem and it was because of 3.80.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question specified that doing a proper upgrade (i.e., upgrading the system's GNU Make package) is out of the question. However, since you have privileges to the system C compiler, I recommend building GNU Make 3.82 (latest and greatest) and installing it in your home directory for personal use.

Software is at: http://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/make/

Unpack it, configure, build, and install:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

Note that the last step is not prefixed by 'sudo'. This will install 'make' as ~/bin/make. After configuring FFmpeg, call '~/bin/make` and everything should build fine.

I just tested this myself.