# Building FFMPEG on UBUNTU facing issue while compiling common.mak file

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, ubuntu-14.04

I am compiling the ffmpeg library i am facing some issues while compiling this.

I follow the steps of compilation form  [here](http://www.roman10.net/2013/08/18/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/).But i am failed to compile.
The issues are as below.

```
WARNING: /home/sumit/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config not found, library detection may fail.
libavcodec/bsf_list.c is unchanged
libavformat/protocol_list.c is unchanged
common.mak:26: *** unterminated call to function `foreach': missing `)'.  Stop.
common.mak:26: *** unterminated call to function `foreach': missing `)'.  Stop.
common.mak:26: *** unterminated call to function `foreach': missing `)'.  Stop.
sumit@sumit-H81M-S:~/android-ndk-r10e/sources/ffmpeg$
```

here is my build_android.sh file-

```
#!/bin/bash

NDK=$HOME/android-ndk-r10e

SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/

TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86

function build_one

{
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-avdevice --disable-doc --disable-symver --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --target-os=linux --arch=arm --enable-cross-compile --sysroot=$SYSROOT --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" 
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}

CPU=arm

PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 

ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"

build_one
```

common.mak-

```
#
# common bits used by all libraries
#

# first so "all" becomes default target
all: all-yes

DEFAULT_YASMD=.dbg

ifeq ($(DBG),1)
YASMD=$(DEFAULT_YASMD)
else
YASMD=
endif

ifndef SUBDIR

ifndef V
Q      = @
ECHO   = printf "$(1)\t%s\n" $(2)
BRIEF  = CC CXX OBJCC HOSTCC HOSTLD AS YASM AR LD STRIP CP WINDRES
SILENT = DEPCC DEPHOSTCC DEPAS DEPYASM RANLIB RM

MSG    = $@
M      = @$(call ECHO,$(TAG),$@);
$(foreach VAR,$(BRIEF), \
    $(eval override $(VAR) = @$$(call ECHO,$(VAR),$$(MSG)); $($(VAR))))
$(foreach VAR,$(SILENT),$(eval override $(VAR) = @$($(VAR))))
$(eval INSTALL = @$(call ECHO,INSTALL,$$(^:$(SRC_DIR)/%=%)); $(INSTALL))
endif

ALLFFLIBS = avcodec avdevice avfilter avformat avresample avutil postproc swscale swresample

# NASM requires -I path terminated with /
IFLAGS     := -I. -I$(SRC_LINK)/
CPPFLAGS   := $(IFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)
CFLAGS     += $(ECFLAGS)
CCFLAGS     = $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
OBJCFLAGS  += $(EOBJCFLAGS)
OBJCCFLAGS  = $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJCFLAGS)
ASFLAGS    := $(CPPFLAGS) $(ASFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS   += $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
YASMFLAGS  += $(IFLAGS:%=%/) -Pconfig.asm

HOSTCCFLAGS = $(IFLAGS) $(HOSTCPPFLAGS) $(HOSTCFLAGS)
LDFLAGS    := $(ALLFFLIBS:%=$(LD_PATH)lib%) $(LDFLAGS)

define COMPILE
       $(call $(1)DEP,$(1))
       $($(1)) $($(1)FLAGS) $($(1)_DEPFLAGS) $($(1)_C) $($(1)_O) $(patsubst $(SRC_PATH)/%,$(SRC_LINK)/%,$<)
endef

COMPILE_C = $(call COMPILE,CC)
COMPILE_CXX = $(call COMPILE,CXX)
COMPILE_S = $(call COMPILE,AS)
COMPILE_M = $(call COMPILE,OBJCC)
COMPILE_HOSTC = $(call COMPILE,HOSTCC)

%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE_C)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(COMPILE_CXX)

%.o: %.m
    $(COMPILE_M)

%.s: %.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -S -o $@ $<

%.o: %.S
    $(COMPILE_S)

%_host.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE_HOSTC)

%.o: %.rc
    $(WINDRES) $(IFLAGS) --preprocessor "$(DEPWINDRES) -E -xc-header -DRC_INVOKED $(CC_DEPFLAGS)" -o $@ $<

%.i: %.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(CC_E) $<

%.h.c:
    $(Q)echo '#include "$*.h"' >$@

%.ver: %.v
    $(Q)sed 's/$$MAJOR/$($(basename $(@F))_VERSION_MAJOR)/' $^ | sed -e 's/:/:\
/' -e 's/; /;\
/g' > $@

%.c %.h: TAG = GEN

# Dummy rule to stop make trying to rebuild removed or renamed headers
%.h:
    @:

# Disable suffix rules.  Most of the builtin rules are suffix rules,
# so this saves some time on slow systems.
.SUFFIXES:

# Do not delete intermediate files from chains of implicit rules
$(OBJS):
endif

include $(SRC_PATH)/arch.mak

OBJS      += $(OBJS-yes)
SLIBOBJS  += $(SLIBOBJS-yes)
FFLIBS    := $($(NAME)_FFLIBS) $(FFLIBS-yes) $(FFLIBS)
TESTPROGS += $(TESTPROGS-yes)

LDLIBS       = $(FFLIBS:%=%$(BUILDSUF))
FFEXTRALIBS := $(LDLIBS:%=$(LD_LIB)) $(EXTRALIBS)

OBJS      := $(sort $(OBJS:%=$(SUBDIR)%))
SLIBOBJS  := $(sort $(SLIBOBJS:%=$(SUBDIR)%))
TESTOBJS  := $(TESTOBJS:%=$(SUBDIR)%) $(TESTPROGS:%=$(SUBDIR)%-test.o)
TESTPROGS := $(TESTPROGS:%=$(SUBDIR)%-test$(EXESUF))
HOSTOBJS  := $(HOSTPROGS:%=$(SUBDIR)%.o)
HOSTPROGS := $(HOSTPROGS:%=$(SUBDIR)%$(HOSTEXESUF))
TOOLS     += $(TOOLS-yes)
TOOLOBJS  := $(TOOLS:%=tools/%.o)
TOOLS     := $(TOOLS:%=tools/%$(EXESUF))
HEADERS   += $(HEADERS-yes)

PATH_LIBNAME = $(foreach NAME,$(1),lib$(NAME)/$($(2)LIBNAME))
DEP_LIBS := $(foreach lib,$(FFLIBS),$(call PATH_LIBNAME,$(lib),$(CONFIG_SHARED:yes=S)))
STATIC_DEP_LIBS := $(foreach lib,$(FFLIBS),$(call PATH_LIBNAME,$(lib)))

SRC_DIR    := $(SRC_PATH)/lib$(NAME)
ALLHEADERS := $(subst $(SRC_DIR)/,$(SUBDIR),$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.h $(SRC_DIR)/$(ARCH)/*.h))
SKIPHEADERS += $(ARCH_HEADERS:%=$(ARCH)/%) $(SKIPHEADERS-)
SKIPHEADERS := $(SKIPHEADERS:%=$(SUBDIR)%)
HOBJS        = $(filter-out $(SKIPHEADERS:.h=.h.o),$(ALLHEADERS:.h=.h.o))
checkheaders: $(HOBJS)
.SECONDARY:   $(HOBJS:.o=.c)

alltools: $(TOOLS)

$(HOSTOBJS): %.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE_HOSTC)

$(HOSTPROGS): %$(HOSTEXESUF): %.o
    $(HOSTLD) $(HOSTLDFLAGS) $(HOSTLD_O) $^ $(HOSTLIBS)

$(OBJS):     | $(sort $(dir $(OBJS)))
$(HOBJS):    | $(sort $(dir $(HOBJS)))
$(HOSTOBJS): | $(sort $(dir $(HOSTOBJS)))
$(SLIBOBJS): | $(sort $(dir $(SLIBOBJS)))
$(TESTOBJS): | $(sort $(dir $(TESTOBJS)))
$(TOOLOBJS): | tools

OBJDIRS := $(OBJDIRS) $(dir $(OBJS) $(HOBJS) $(HOSTOBJS) $(SLIBOBJS) $(TESTOBJS))

CLEANSUFFIXES     = *.d *.o *~ *.h.c *.map *.ver *.ver-sol2 *.ho *.gcno *.gcda *$(DEFAULT_YASMD).asm
DISTCLEANSUFFIXES = *.pc
LIBSUFFIXES       = *.a *.lib *.so *.so.* *.dylib *.dll *.def *.dll.a

define RULES
clean::
    $(RM) $(HOSTPROGS)
    $(RM) $(TOOLS)
endef

$(eval $(RULES))

-include $(wildcard $(OBJS:.o=.d) $(HOSTOBJS:.o=.d) $(TESTOBJS:.o=.d) $(HOBJS:.o=.d) $(SLIBOBJS:.o=.d)) $(OBJS:.o=$(DEFAULT_YASMD).d)
```

Comment: Did you read the comments in your original link?

Comment: Yes i read the comments from the link the said replace these 3 lines make clean
make
make install                                                                                          with                                                                                $HOME/bin/make clean
$HOME/bin/make
$HOME/bin/make install   but this solution is not working for me, it gives missing bin directory error @MorrisonChang

Comment: So you followed http://stackoverflow.com/a/9627460/295004 and have a recent version of make?

Comment: I also tried these suggestion but result is same @MorrisonChang